# Падеж числительного в сказуемом

Tags: грамматика

Допустимо ли оставить числительное "одно" в именительном падеже?

Чудес незаметных - так много, 
Заметных чудес - ни одно.

Comment: Первое тире совершенно не нужно.

Comment: Почему совершенно не нужно?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ исправлен

***Чудес незаметных — так много, 
Заметного чуда — (нет) ни одного.***

При наличии отрицательной частицы НИ используется только родительный падеж.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

**Родительный падеж**, имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции значение **подчеркнутого отрицания**, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:

1)      при наличии в предложении **частицы НИ** или начинающихся с частицы НИ местоимения или наречия, например: Да мы не имеем **ни малейшего понятия** о том, что делается с этими несчастными... (Л. Толстой);

Comment: Имеется в виду как бы пропущенная (замест нее - тире) связка "быть": "Заметных частей есть ни одно".

Comment: А если рассматривать эту конструкцию как две отдельные части: "Заметных чудес - ни одно (не заметно)"? Заметных чудес... Ни одно!

Comment: (Я исправила ответ, мне он показался неправильным). В комментарии неверная конструкция. Правильно: Заметного чуда нет ни одного. Возможен также такой вариант:   Незаметные чудеса случаются часто. Из заметных чудес не случилось ни одно

Comment: > Почему первое тире "совершенно не нужно"? Есть правило, запрещающее ставить тире в подобных предложениях? Отвечаю @Sharon здесь, поскольку комментарии мне запрещены. В правилах никаких запретов нет вообще, а в правилах есть *указания*, в каких случаях *ставятся* знаки препинания. И это логично, верно? Так вот, первое тире здесь не ставится, потому что для постановки нет оснований. Разумеется, авторское тире можно ставить почти где угодно, тем более если это стихи. А это, похоже, стихи, вернее, попытка.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В первом предложении интонационное тире, его постановка связана с инверсией (чудес незамЕтных - так много), а также с параллельной конструкцией двух предложений. (Но музыкальность фразы точно не соблюдена).  Сравнить: Незаметных чудес так мнОго...  При прямом порядке слов для интонационного тире гораздо меньше оснований, а без тире инверсию просто не объяснишь.

Comment: Да, это отрывок из стихотворения. Фигуры ложились рядами, Надуманными чередами, Запутанными в клубок. Как хочешь, играй с виденьем: Хоть переверни всё с ног, Хоть перерисуй набок. Чудес незаметных - как много! Заметных чудес - ни одно, И бесповоротна дорога.